# change the width of columns in listgrids

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I have a `ListGrid` created, and there are 3 or 4 columns. How do I change the width of these columns so the information can be displayed without having to re-size them every refresh?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

The width can be set for each column in the ListGridField constructor. See: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGridField.html

For an example usage see:
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_appearance_columnsize

Alternatively there is a method on ListGrid to auto fit the column to it's contents. See:
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html#autoFitField(java.lang.String)